# CheckBox [Entering the index to database]

Tags: c#, asp.net

Add a check box to the form and then how to insert respective value 1 if checked else 0 to the database where I have a field which is of type integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
int checked = (CheckBox.Checked)? 1 : 0
```

That will convert the value to an int and then you can store the int value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
If(myCheckBox.Checked)
{
// set 1 
}
else
{
// set 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a 'bit' type designed for holding a boolean value in MS SQL - I'm sure other databases have similar types.

As opposed to using an int.